# Wordpress hide specific file directory for all users except admin and owner

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to hide a specific file directory "`<https://site.nl/wp-content/uploads/useruploads/[user_nicename][user_id]/test.pdf>"`

But only the admin and the user that matches with the folder should be able to view the content.

**Idea behind this:**

- User can upload files.
- When uploading file it creates the folder.
- Only user that is admin or matches can view the folder.

**What I tried so far.**

- Adding code to my .htaccess file so its no longer reachable.
  `# Deny access to any files in this directory <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> RewriteEngine On RewriteBase / RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/useruploads/ - [F,L] </IfModule>`
- Also added 1 file that check if the file is created and if it matches then it echo's the file in the header. This works sort of but Is this safe?

(problem I currently have is that on each refresh it downloads a file)

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../../../wp-load.php');
if (!is_admin()) {
    $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $current_user_info = get_userdata($current_user_id);
    $username = $current_user_info->user_nicename;

    $directory_path = WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/useruploads/' . $username . $current_user_id;

    if (file_exists($directory_path) && is_dir($directory_path)) {
        $dir = opendir($directory_path);
        echo '<h2>Your Uploaded Files:</h2>';
        echo '<ul>';

        while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
            if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
                echo '<li><a href="#" onclick="downloadFile(\'' . urlencode($file) . '\')">' . $file . '</a></li>';
            }
        }
        echo '</ul>';
        closedir($dir);
    } else {
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($directory_path);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
}
?>

<script>
function downloadFile(fileName) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = '<?php echo home_url('/file-access.php?file='); ?>' + fileName;
    link.download = fileName;

    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}
</script>
```

File to create the download:

```
<?php
if (!is_admin()) {
    if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
    $file = isset($_GET['file']) ? $_GET['file'] : '';
    $file = sanitize_file_name($file);

    $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $current_user_info = get_userdata($current_user_id);
    $username = $current_user_info->user_nicename;

    $directory_path = WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/useruploads/' . $username . $current_user_id;
    $file_path = $directory_path . '/' . $file;

    if (file_exists($directory_path) && is_dir($directory_path)) {
        if (file_exists($file_path) && is_readable($file_path)) {
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file_path) . '"'); // Use basename to get the file name
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_path));

            readfile($file_path);
            exit;
        } else {
            wp_die('File not found or access denied.');
        }
    } else {
        wp_die('Directory not found.');
    }
}
} else {
    echo 'This script is only accessible on the front end.';
}
?>
```

Comment: _"it seems to be working but"_ - it seems like you intended to give a problem description there but

Comment: @CBroe Sorry, I updated the post sometimes i get "rubberd ducky" when I write a question in stackoverflow. And try a solution in the middle of it.

Comment: The checks you do on the directory path are a bit superfluous. `is_readable` can't return true, if the file can't be found in the first place. And if the path _to_ the file location doesn't exist to begin with, it will also return false. `is_readable($file_path) && is_file($file_path)` should be completely sufficient at this point. (`is_file`, because `is_readable` doesn't differentiate between files and folders. And if a user passed you a path segment instead of a file name, you don't want to continue.)

Comment: And the `downloadFile` JS function also looks rather superfluous - you might as well output `<?php echo home_url('/file-access.php?file=') . urlencode($file); ?>` as the content of the `href` attribute of the link to begin with, and remove the JS.

Comment: One thing you have not taken into account yet, is the possibility of _path traversal_ attacks. If I pass a `file` parameter to your script, that is not just a plain file name, but something like `../foo.txt` - then I would be able to "break out" of the user directory. And if I also know the username, user id and name of a file of a different user - then I could pass `../username1234/filename.txt`, and would be able to _get_ that file. Apply `realpath` to the assembled file path first - and then check if it _starts with_ the path to the user directory.

Comment: @CBroe That is what my main concern is. is path traversal attacks. This might not be the way to handle all of this. At the time I tought this would be the best approach but I might be better to use the wordpress api or database to store the files? What do you think would be the best approach?

Comment: As I said, you can thwart the path traversal attack, by using `realpath`, and then checking if the result still starts with the expected path. `/uploads/useruploads/name1234/` is your base path for the current user, and you get `../foo.txt` passed for the `file` parameter - so that results in `/uploads/useruploads/name1234/../foo.txt`. Apply `realpath`, and this will get resolved to `/uploads/useruploads/foo.txt`. Now you check if _that_ string, still starts with `/uploads/useruploads/name1234/` ... it doesn't, so someone is trying to break out of their directory here.

Comment: (`realpath` will actually return a full absolute path from the server root directory, not just something that starts at `/uploads/...` - but `WP_CONTENT_DIR` should also include that, so your `$directory_path` should also be starting there to begin with, so that checking if one starts with the other, should still work fine with the absolute paths.)

Comment: @CBroe This might sound stupid. But would it be better to disable access to the directory `/useruploads/` and rewrite the link to a `download.php` that handles the downloading of the file?

Comment: Not sure why you are asking this at this point; that is _already_ what you are doing, no? (You said you disabled access to the directory, and the download is already handled via the download.php as shown.) But the path traversal issue of course still needs to be handled in the download script - because that finds the file based on a parameter passed from the client, which could have been manipulated.

Comment: @CBroe sorry, I am pretty new to this stuff so some things you are saying is hocuspocus for me haha, :/